# How to create transform for .msi file using c#

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I'm trying to create a transform for .msi file in C#. Here is my code:

```
 public static void CreateTransforms(string original_MSI, string backup_MSI, string MSTpath, string query)
    {
        File.Copy(original_MSI, backup_MSI, true);
        using (var origDatabase = new Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database(original_MSI, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
        {
            using (var database = new Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database(backup_MSI, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
            {
                //database.Execute("Update `Property` Set `Property`.`Value` = 'Test' WHERE `Property`.`Property` = 'ProductName'");
                database.Execute(query);
                database.GenerateTransform(origDatabase, MSTpath);
                database.CreateTransformSummaryInfo(origDatabase, MSTpath, TransformErrors.None, TransformValidations.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the following error : "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package." in the step create transform summary info. I used "Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" library. Any help would be great.

Comment: Error 1620, package could not be opened is typically from an API like MsiOpenPackage, not MsiOpenDatabase that your code uses - OpenDabase doesn't care that it's a valid MSI like the other other "open for run" APIs do. For example you get error 1620 if you do an MsiOpenPackage on an MSI with a missing PackageCode, but NOT with MsiOpenDatabase. That's a bit of a disconnect to me, so look carefully because I don't think I've seen OpenDatabase get a 1620. And yes, that code runs ok for me too. You'd get 1619 if the DB was already open, but that's not the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of this static method looked correct so I created a console app out of it.  It works fine for me on my machine.  I would look at your calling method and make sure the data being passed is correct.  I get really nervous any time I have a method that takes 4 strings as arguments as that leaves a lot to desire in terms of type safety.

Answer (score 0):

when CreateTransforms start, it open database and it does not close it ...
you must commit and close the database before apply a new transform!

```
                database.GenerateTransform(origDatabase, TRANSFORM);
                database.CreateTransformSummaryInfo(origDatabase, TRANSFORM, TransformErrors.None, TransformValidations.None);
                database.Commit();
                database.Close();
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the database IDispose will handle the commit and close automatically. In his example the database object was inside a using statement.

Comment: ....and even if the handle wasn't closed you'd get error 1619 on attempting to open it, but the reported error corresponds to error 1620.